# Scrolling stutters when loading from firebase in flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview, stream-builder

I'm loading data from a Firebase collection into Listview of Cards. The problem is when I try to scroll I encounter micro stutters. They usually happen just as a new Card is about to appear in the view. It is happening in the web release build on both MacOS and IOS.

This is my code:

```
class MyGameList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('games').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
        return GameCard(
          anim: data['anim'],
          name: data['name'],
          tags: List<String>.from(data['tags'] ?? []),
          dropdownValue: data['dropdownValue'],
          year: data['year'],
          minutes: data['minutes'],
          goal: data['goal'],
          rules: data['rules'],
          responsibility: data['responsibility'],
          props: data['props'],
          good: data['good'],
          bad: data['bad'],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

When I try to manually generate data and create Listview of Cards from it, it works much better and scrolling is almost flawless.

This is the code for generated data:

```
class MyTestGameList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> gamesData = List.generate(
    100, // Generates 100 items for test
        (index) => {
      'anim': 'Animator $index',
      'name': 'Game $index',
      'tags': ['Tag1', 'Tag2'],
      'dropdownValue': 'Camp $index',
      'year': '202${index % 10}',
      'minutes': '${20 + index}',
      'goal': 'Goal of Game $index'*2,
      'rules': 'Rules of Game $index'*20,
      'responsibility': 'Responsibility in Game $index'*3,
      'props': 'Props for Game $index'*2,
      'good': 'Good aspects of Game $index'*5,
      'bad': 'Improvements for Game $index'*5,
    },
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: gamesData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var game = gamesData[index];
        return GameCard(
          anim: game['anim'],
          name: game['name'],
          tags: game['tags'],
          dropdownValue: game['dropdownValue'],
          year: game['year'],
          minutes: game['minutes'],
          goal: game['goal'],
          rules: game['rules'],
          responsibility: game['responsibility'],
          props: game['props'],
          good: game['good'],
          bad: game['bad'],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? My cards contain no images and just a bit of text. I even tried building with canvaskit which didn't help.